# How can I validate console input as integers?

Tags: c#, validation, console

I have written my codes and i want to validate it in such a way thet it will only allow intergers to be inputed and not alphabets. Here is the code, please I will love you to help me. Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace minimum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (a < b)
            {
                if (a < c)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a + "is the minimum number");
                }
            }
            if (b < a)
            {
                if (b < c)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(b + "is the minimum number");
                }
            }
            if (c < a)
            {
                if (c < b)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(c + "is the minimum number");
                }
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You should test if it's an int instead of converting in right away.
Try something like :

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int value;
if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
{
   // this is an int
   // do you minimum number check here
}
else
{
   // this is not an int
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Simply call Readline() and loop with Int.TryParse until the user inputs a valid number :)

```
int X;

String Result = Console.ReadLine();

while(!Int32.TryParse(Result, out X))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Not a valid number, try again.");

   Result = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 9):

To get the console to filter out alphabetical keystrokes you have to take over input parsing.  The Console.ReadKey() method is fundamental to this, it lets you sniff the pressed key.  Here's a sample implementation:

```
    static string ReadNumber() {
        var buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (; ; ) {
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && buf.Length > 0) {
                return buf.ToString() ;
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && buf.Length > 0) {
                buf.Remove(buf.Length-1, 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
            else if ("0123456789.-".Contains(key.KeyChar)) {
                buf.Append(key.KeyChar);
                Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            }
            else {
                Console.Beep();
            }
        }
    }
```

You could add, say, Decimal.TryParse() in the if() statement that detects the Enter key to verify that the entered string is still a valid number.  That way you can reject input like "1-2".

Comment: +1 But you should probably validate for modifiers :-) (Ctrl, Alt...)

Comment: That's true.  Let's call it a feature :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not Convert the input from the user immediately. Put it in a string and use Int32.TryParse(...) to find out whether or not a number was entered. Like this:

```
int i;
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if(Int32.TryParse(input, out i))
{
    // it is a number and it is stored in i
}
else
{
    // it is not a number
}
```

Comment: WOW is that a record having all these solutions thrown in at the same time? Should we delete them?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
if (a < b) {
    if (a < c) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a < b && a < c) {
```

and that this latter form introduces less nesting and is more readable, particularly if your code grows more complex.  Also, you should probably **never** use `Convert.ToInt32` - it has a particularly ill-conceived and surprising corner case; and it's also less type-safe than  `int.Parse` which is the superior choice where possible - or `int.TryParse` when you're unsure whether the string is valid.  Basically, avoid `Convert....` wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
        string Temp;
        int tempInt,a;
        bool result=false;
        while ( result == false )
            {
            Console.Write ("\n Enter A Number : ");
            Temp = Console.ReadLine ();
            result = int.TryParse (Temp, out tempInt);
            if ( result == false )
                {
                Console.Write ("\n Please Enter Numbers Only.");
                }
            else
                {
                a=tempInt;
                break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution would be:

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        (
            from line in Generate(()=>Console.ReadLine()).Take(3)
            let val = ParseAsInt(line)
            where val.HasValue
            select val.Value
        ).Min()
    );
}
static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> generator) { 
   while(true) yield return generator(); 
}
static int? ParseAsInt(string str) {
   int retval; 
   return int.TryParse(str,out retval) ? retval : default(int?); 
}
```

Of course, depending on the specification (should invalid number be retried?), it may need to be tweaked.

Comment: The code? a puzzle? hmm, that's not good :-) - I intended to make the functionality compositional and avoid large functions - I suppose the generate function takes a little getting used to...

Answer (score 0):

**Double/Float:**

I'm just extending @Hans Passant answer (Taking care of DecimalSeparator and "-"):

```
    static double ReadNumber()
    {
        var buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (; ; )
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter && buf.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                return Convert.ToDouble(buf.ToString());
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && buf.Length > 0)
            {
                buf.Remove(buf.Length - 1, 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
            else if (System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator.Contains(key.KeyChar) && buf.ToString().IndexOf(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator) == -1)
            {
                buf.Append(key.KeyChar);
                Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            }
            else if ("-".Contains(key.KeyChar) && buf.ToString().IndexOf("-") == -1 && buf.ToString() == "")
            {
                buf.Append(key.KeyChar);
                Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            }
            else if ("0123456789".Contains(key.KeyChar))
            {
                buf.Append(key.KeyChar);
                Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Beep();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var getInput=Console.ReadLine();
    int option;        
    //validating input
        while(!int.TryParse(getInput, out option))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input type. Please try again");
            getInput=Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This Simple

```
try
{
    string x= "aaa";
    Convert.ToInt16(x);
    //if success is integer not go to catch
}
catch
{
    //if not integer 
    return;
}
```