# Console.ReadKey(false) in C# something fishy about it

Tags: c#

i am trying to make a simple application in C# in which every character I type is displayed in a console window. Here is my code :

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.ConsoleKeyInfo input;
            input = Console.ReadKey(false);
            String d = input.ToString();
            char c = d[0];
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the characters are not displayed correctly, and to be more precise, every character is followed by an 'S'. For example i type 'a' and i get 'aS' instead of 'a'. Any solutions?  Thnx in advance!

Comment: input.ToString() doesn't do what you think it does, easily seen with a debugger.  Check this answer for code that shows you how to use the KeyChar property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804968/how-can-i-validate-console-input-as-integers/4805314#4805314

Answer (score 4):

What you are seeing is the following:

- The original character you entered, since you passed `false` not `true` to `ReadKey`
- The first characters of the string "System.ConsoleKeyInfo", since the `ToString()` method returns the typename (here), not the character entered.

Use the following code instead to achieve what you attempted:

```
while(true)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey(true);
    Console.WriteLine(info.KeyChar);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `input.ToString() == "System.ConsoleKeyInfo"` :-)
Depending on what you want to do, try writing `input.KeyChar`.

Comment: ...which has a property that contains the actual character.

Comment: @bzlm No KeyChar is a char with the key. So if you press `A` it will be `A`. If you press `F1` it will be ``\0`` and you'll have to look in the Key property to see what key was pressed

Answer (score 1):

The parameter of `Console.ReadKey(false);` defines if the key you type is intercepted or not. So `Console.ReadKey(false);` prints the character you type and `Console.Writeline(c)` prints the `S`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `char c = input.KeyChar;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `ToString()` on a `System.ConsoleKeyInfo`. When this is turned into a string you will get `"System.ConsoleKeyInfo"` and the first character is therefore `'S'`. Did you mean to write the following code instead?

```
while (true)
{
    var input = Console.ReadKey(false);
    Console.WriteLine(input.KeyChar);
}
```

With that code each character will get duplicated (so you will get `aabbccddee`). Change the `false` to `true` in `ReadKey` to fix that.