# Input Validity checks in C# console base application

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I validate console input as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804968/how-can-i-validate-console-input-as-integers)

I am developing a console base application in C#. In which i want when a user prompt to enter the integer then user can type only integer and when an user prompt to enter string, he can only type string. Please help me.

Thanks in advance and regards.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
int i;
while (true)
{
  var line = Console.ReadLine();
  if (int.TryParse(line, out i))
    break;
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the integer check, you can use the int.TryParse() as mentioned by maxlego. Or you can use a "try... catch" block although I don't see a reason to do so.

For the string case, I'm not sure what you meant by "he can only type string". While technically whatever "he" types will be a string anyway, I'll assume you meant to filter out numbers, such that "J0hns0n" is not a valid last name: You can do this by checking the ASCII code for each character. Here's the doc from MSDN regarding splitting a string into an array of chars: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx and here's the ASCII Table: http://www.asciitable.com/ you can filter out, for example, 48-57 (i.e. number 0 ~ 9) from a string.