# Output an enum positions name in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum Planet which contains all 8 planets:

```
enum Planet
{
    MERCURY, VENUS, EARTH, MARS,
    JUPITER, SATURN, URANUS, NEPTUNE
}
```

I need to take an int position and output the corresponding enums position planet name.

So if the user entered in 2 for position, and position 2 in the enum was EARTH. It would output EARTH.

I tried using:

```
// Planetary Position.
Console.Write("Please enter a numeric position: ");
int position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

// Output of selected planet.
Console.Write(Enum.GetName(typeof(Planet), position));

// Prevents CMD Prompt from closing.
Console.Read();
```

But nothing happens when you enter in the number.

**NOTE: We have not delved into any if statements or anything like that.

Comment: That's not what enums are used for. They're there to give a readable name to a constant. Use a dictionary object instead, with numbers as keys, and names as values. Also fyi, ENUMs start at 0, unless you specify an initial value.

Comment: You could cast the int to enum? `Planet p = (Planet)position;`

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy There may be a better way, but we have only just begun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are taking the input is wrong it should be:

```
int position = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

`Console.Read` reads a character and returns its ASCII value, for example for `2` you will get `50` in position, and since there is no value in your enum for `50` you get `null` back and thus nothing is written on the console.

*(You can use `int.TryParse` for parsing input from console, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805019/961113))*

You can also do:

```
Console.Write((Planet)position);
```

*(and don't forget [Pluto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto))*

Comment: Ah, thank you! I was trying to go by memory and Console.Read was not giving any errors.

Comment: `(and don't forget Pluto)` Pluto is not a planet any more :(

Comment: @L.B, ohhh now it is a  `dwarf planet` :)