# How to multiply values with c#?

Tags: c#

my Question is how can i get the code below to accept numbers only and only multiply when a number above 5 is entered.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of tickets sold for movie x or 1 to exit now!");
int adult = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int total1 = 30 * adult;
if (adult >= 5 && adult <= 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The total cost for the adults tickets is : {0}", total1);
}
else if (adult == 1)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error for adults");
}
Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of tickets sold for z or y to exit now!");
int child = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int total2 = 20 * child;
if (child >= 5 && child <= 30)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The total cost for the child tickets is : {0}", total2);
}
else if (child == 1)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error for child");
}
int finTotal = total1 + total2;
Console.WriteLine("The cost of all the tickets together is : {0}", finTotal);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Please use formatting

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the *total1* and *total2* inside the **if condition**. I don't understand why you are calculating the total1 and total2 outside the if statement.

Eg:

```
if (child >= 5 && child<= 30)
{
   int total2 = 20 * child;
   Console.WriteLine("The total cost for the child tickets is : {0}", total2);
}
```

Edit1: In order to accept numbers only, have a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804968/how-can-i-validate-console-input-as-integers):

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I left out your else if statement but you can write those back in.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            int totalAmount = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Insert the number of adult tickets sold (1 for exit)");    
            int adultTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if(adultTickets >= 5 && adultTickets <= 30)
            {
                totalAmount = adultTickets * 30;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Insert the number of child tickets sold (1 for exit)");
            int childTickets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if(childTickets >= 5 && childTickets <= 30)
            {
                totalAmount += childTickets * 20;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(totalAmount);
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value input was not an integer.");
        }
   }
}
```