# How to block the user from typing text

Tags: c#

I'm recreating the game Hammurabi (just an assignment for my uni) and I want somehow my code to check if the user is typing text so it gets in a while loop to prompt him to type text. I know how to make the user type the numbers I want him to but I don't know how to fix it if he types something like "a" then my program will bug.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
while (acresToBuy < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type a positive number or 0");
    acresToBuy = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

int cost = trade * acresToBuy;
while (cost > bushels)
{
    Console.WriteLine("We have but " + bushels + " bushels of grain,    not " + cost);
    acresToBuy = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    cost = trade * acresToBuy;
}
```

Comment: if you just want to make your code not error out, use a try/catch block. If you want to repeat asking for input until you get a proper number, then do so in some loop that checks the input as convertible to int and if not true repeat the request for a number.

Comment: Look this as your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804968/how-can-i-validate-console-input-as-integers @Hans Passant's answer. The point is to use ReadKey(), instead of ReadLine(), so you can validate the key during a single character input.

Comment: Use try parse instead of parse. If tryparse returns false then they didn't enter an int and ask them again

Comment: So write tryparse and check if it's false then repeat the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Int.TryParse` for this. For example:

```
while (acresToBuy < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type a positive number or 0");
    acresToBuy = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out acresToBuy) ? acresToBuy : -1;
}
```

If `Int.TryParse` fails, then the method will return false, in which then we assign -1 to acresToBuy, otherwise, if it succeeds, we simply assign it back to itself.

Comment: You can't check `acresToBuy < 0` if it has no value, and you can't use it as an `out` parameter if it has a value.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `int.Parse` (or other types' equivalents) unless you can absolutely guarantee that the input will be parsable, and that's something you cannot do where user input is involved. Instead, you should use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please type a positive number or 0");

    int input;
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
        && input >= 0) // You can validate the input at the same time
    {
        acresToBuy = input;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("That was not the correct input. Please try again.");
        acresToBuy = -1;
    }
} while (acresToBuy < 0);
```

**Edit:** The `while` loop will always check it's condition first before executing, so keep in mind that your code will only run if `acresToBuy` has an initial value of something less than 0 (i.e. -1). To prevent from having to constantly check this against pre-existing conditions, you should instead use a `do-while` loop, which will always run at least once.

Comment: This will work only if the user types something less than 0 though cause it's inside that while loop. I want to check the whole thing at once.

Edit: just realised I posted only that code. Sorry my bad.

Comment: @SadonEmsi The `while` loop is doing what it's supposed to, though it assumes that `acresToBuy` starts with an initial value of something less than 0 (i.e. -1). In fairness, it would be better to replace the `while` loop with a `do-while` loop so the logic isn't interfered with by any pre-existing conditions.

Comment: Okay now I understand, but what does exactly the out function do? It returns the value to the input variable?

Comment: @SadonEmsi The `out` keyword (along with the `ref` keyword) makes it so the parameter is passed by reference instead of by value. Basically, that means any changes you make to the parameter inside the method will happen to the variable that you passed to that method as well. You can read more about them [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/parameter).