# How to write a function that takes an integer as a parameter and calculates and returns the squared value

Tags: c#

Ahoy! I have just started methods but I am a tad confused when it comes to methods with math. First post so be nice :) I'm aware I out in NumberToSquare way too many times!
Write a program that asks the user to enter a number.  In your program write a function called SquareValue that takes an integer parameter and calculates the square of integer parameter and returns this squared value.  Your program should take this returned square value and display it.  An example of the output is:
Please enter a number to square:  8
/ 8 squared is:  64

What I have so far is not so comprehensible. I thought along a few different avenues and was unsure as to what to delete. Help please.

```
namespace SquareValue
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int number=NumberToSquare();
            SquareValue(NumberToSquare * NumberToSquare);
            string output;

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public int SquareValue(NumberToSquare, NumberToSquare);
        {
            int result = NumberToSquare * NumberToSquare;

            return result;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} squared is "+result");
    }

        public int NumberToSquare()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to square: ");
        int NumberToSquare = Console.ReadLine();
        return NumberToSquare;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` [returns a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx), not an int - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805019/43846

Comment: `SquareValue()` has two parameters (with the name name!?), but you're only passing it one - which is **already** squared.

Comment: .. and you're not actually _using_ the return value from `SquareValue()`

Comment: Have you tried executing the above code? You shouldn't be getting the output for your above program. 

Your main method is Static. You can not invoke a non-static method from a static method.

NumberToSquare() is not a static method. 

Execute your code before posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you stuartd and Neeraj Kumar. I have redone the code passing just one parameter and making the appropriate amendments. We were given Methods exercises in class for homework but were not taught now to create a method/ function, pass parameters etc, but this has now been addressed. Thank you, and apologies for any inconvenience :)

Comment: But it doesn't even compile (also indicated by the weird syntax highlighting). Just by inspection, the quotes aren't balanced (also noticed in [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656195/how-to-write-a-function-that-takes-an-integer-as-a-parameter-and-calculates-and/46656591#46656591)): `Console.WriteLine("{0} squared is "+result")`; Neither are the `{}`'s (near the same place). Some code seems to have been deleted before it was posted.

Comment: Re "was unsure as to what to delete": What does that mean?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing your methods, make them reusable. When you start using a method to output to the console in addition to its primary purpose (i.e. to square a number), its re-usability becomes minimal. It is much better to keep specific code in your main method, and put sub tasks into separate methods, such as squaring a number. Now, whenever you need to square a number, you already have a perfectly good method for that.

I didn't handle the case for users entering bad input, but that can be done in the else of the TryParse if block.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int squredNum = 0;
    int NumberToSquare = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to square: ");
    if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out NumberToSquare))
    {
        squredNum = SquareValue(NumberToSquare);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} squared is {1}", NumberToSquare, squredNum);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static int SquareValue(int numberToSquare)
{
    return numberToSquare * numberToSquare;
}
```

p.s. I would not recommend using `Math.Pow()` to square a number. No need to kill a fly with a bazooka!

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and also in regards to the Math.Pow(). I decided against using this line and used the multiplication as I did not learn this in class for some reason. Thanks again.

Comment: You're very welcome. Best of luck with your studies, and hope to see you back here one day giving people advice... or asking more questions!

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason to over complicate this:

```
public int Square(int x)
{
  return (x * x);
}
```

or

```
public int Square(int x)
{
   return Math.Pow(x,2);
}
```

Or just use Math.Pow as it exists with 2 as the Power Of number.

Answer (score 1):

You seem very green on programming and I'm not sure SO is a place to go to learn the basics, but I'll run through what you've done and explain what's going wrong.

Your original program concept is fine but there are many issues with basic syntax.  I understand you mightn't be familiar with reading compiler errors so I'll explain the errors that I see just reading through the code...

You put a ; at the end of the `SquareValue(..., ...)` method which teeminates the declaration so the body in braces isn't part of the method, then things go haywire later on.

You're not passing in the value captured from the NumberToSquare method...

```
int number=NumberToSquare();
SquareValue(NumberToSquare * NumberToSquare);
```

`NumberToSquare`  isn't a defined variable so NumberToSquare * NumberToSquare can't calculate, what you'd want is `number * number` where `number is the value entered by the user.

Your definition of int `SquareValue(NumberToSquare, NumberToSquare)` expects two parameters although you haven't speified the type. It should be

```
int SquareValue(int NumberToSquare, int NumberToSquare)
```

but you have the same variable declared twice which is another error and then you aren't passing two parameters anyway.  You want to multiply a number by itself therefore you only have a single source number so why declared two parameters? You need a single parameter method

```
int SquareValue(int NumberToSquare)
```

and call like this

```
int number=NumberToSquare();
SquareValue(number);
```

Now the `SquareValue()` method returns an `int` but you never capture it in the calling code and display the result in the method. Follow the idea in this app that the Main method will do all the orchestration and display, but the `SquareValue()` method should ONLY do a calculation and not any I/O.  I'd also rename the `NumberToSquare()` method a as what is actually happening ... `GetNumberToSquareFromUser()`.

And there's also a stray " before the closing bracket.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} squared is " + result");
```

And you defined a string output variable which is never used.
And your methods need to be static because `main(..)` is a static method, not instance. If you declare a Squaring class and instantiated it then you could call non static methods from that.
Also `ReadLine()` returns a string which can't be assigned to an int.

And finally the result line is implicitly using `String.Format` behind the scenes but you haven't specified the original number for the `{0}` token.  You could also use interpolation.  You could do either of these

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} squared is " + result, number);
Console.WriteLine($"{number} squared is " + result);
```

So here's **your** program revised

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int number = GetNumberToSquareFromUser();
        int result = SquareValue(number);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} squared is " + result, number);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static int SquareValue(int numberToSquare)
    {
        return numberToSquare * numberToSquare;
    }

    public static int GetNumberToSquareFromUser()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number to square: ");
        int NumberToSquare = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return NumberToSquare;
    }

}
```

I hope this help, I know it's alot to take in, but I hope you take the time to read and really understand rather than just blindly submit the revised version.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for your detailed response. I appreciate that SO was not the best place to start. I have spoken to my lecturer as he gave us the exercises without showing us how to create methods, or pass parameters. We have a mixed level class so assumptions were made that we all should already know this even though there are those with several years experience and some with zero. Since my post, we ran through the process step by step in class so I now understand this, and have looked to your revised code for reference. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example of such program with robust handling:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter value to square or X to exit");

                var line = Console.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    continue;

                if (line.Trim().Equals("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exitting ...");
                    break;
                }

                int result;

                if (!int.TryParse(line, out result))
                    continue;

                Console.WriteLine(result * result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See the docs online, understand each statement, write your very own program then as your teacher will likely figure out you didn't pull that solely by yourself :)

Comment: Thanks. There is some code there that I have not seen before but I have been reading through it and breaking it down and it's starting to sink in. I will print it for future reference but write my own program like you said. Cheers :)