# Accept Input from console application in C# other than using Console.ReadLine()

Tags: c#

In C# Console, we use Console.ReadLine() to accept inputs, this method returns the input in System.String format by default.

My question, is there a way/any method to accept input from Console as it is, I mean, if I type Integer then I must get integer in my code without converting the input to String.

Comment: No, everything read from the console is a string.  You have to perform the conversion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443827/reading-an-integer-from-user-input

Comment: The reason why you cant just interpret the datatype is because if a user inputs `0x0F`, do you parse that as a byte or as a string? There is no context as to how the stream reader should read the data buffer. Both a string and a byte are valid types in this scenario, it just all depends on the use case for the data as to what type is appropriate for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805314/17034