# How to stop readline being entered with no value

Tags: c#

Hopefully a quick one, I would just like to know how to stop a Console.Readline(); from being entered without an actual value.

The line of code in question:

```
int xCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

is there a way I can stop the user from pressing enter without entering a value?

When I press enter I get the following:

> Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>      at System.Number.ThrowOverflowOrFormatException(ParsingStatus status, TypeCode type)
>      at System.Number.ParseInt32(ReadOnlySpan`1 value, NumberStyles styles, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
>      at Battleships_Game.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/oliver/Projects/Battleships_Game_Testing/Battleships_Game/Program.cs:line 462

Comment: You want to asynchronously wait for input?

Comment: Read the users input into a variable.  Then check to see if it is valid.  If it isn't, don't try converting it to an integer.

Comment: You'll need to handle invalid input such as letters and punctuation anyway. Best to keep taking input until you get a valid one, as knight8989 has answered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4805314/17034

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop and the [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) Method:

```
int xCoordinate = 0;
int failAttemptsCounter = 0;
// this means: WHILE the Conversion result is FALSE go inside the brackets and repeat the step
while (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out xCoordinate) == false)
{
    failAttemptsCounter++;
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input, please only integers");
    if (failAttemptsCounter > 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop kidding around google what an integer is !");
    }
}

// you end up here only when the conversion has worked
Console.WriteLine(xCoordinate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a loop. Get the input from user into a variable and check for null value. You could use a do-while loop for this. Also could prompt user to enter a valid integer if null exception detected

```
tryParse(string, Int32)
```

would be the best option. You can google it, helps avoid using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to handle this scenario is with a validation loop. For simplicity's sake, I recommend extracting the logic to a separate method. Here is a simple example:

```
int ReadInteger(string prompt)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(response, out result)) return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
int xCoordinate =0;
    while(true){
        try{
        xCoordinate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            break;
        }
        catch{

        }
    }
Console.WriteLine(xCoordinate);
```